# Splitting CSV text file in Java and entering the data into different fields of class

Tags: java, csv, file-io

I have a problem. I am trying to read in a text file containing values separated by spaces (similar to CSV, i think).

I am able to take in the input file, but I don't know how to split it up so that each "value" goes into a different field.

Below, find the section of my code which I have done.

```
 String error = ("Content could not be read. Error loading JFileChooser. Try again.");
    String content = null;
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();  //Displays graphical UI to choose the file
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        try {
            content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(selectedFile.getPath())));
        } catch (Exception IOException) {
            IOException.printStackTrace();
            out.println("Error!");
        }
        //return values read in from file.
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);

        sc.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z]+"); //regular expression

        //return content for use l8r on in the program...
        out.println(content); //test to see if reads in correctly

       return content;
    } else
        return error;
```

This is a sample input the file will contain:

1 2 50 0 George Paradise_3

1 3 50 0 John Somewhere_4

1 4 50 0 Jane Devil’s_place_3

2 50 60 0 George Paradise_13

2 50 60 0 John Somewhere_14

2 60 60 0 Jane Devil’s_place_13

3 10 10 50 0 George Paradise_23

3 15 20 40 0 John Somewhere_24

3 20 30 55 0 Jane Devil’s_place_23

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I have understood your question. maybe StringTokenizer can help you?

Comment: Is there one record per line (like in a csv?)

Comment: @MauricePerry yes! one record per line. I'll modify the question to include a sample of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would read the file with a BufferedReader instead of loading the whole content into a string:

```
File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"); // or whatever
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
    String line = in.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        String[] fields = line.split("\\s");
        doSomethingWith(fields);
        line = in.readLine();
    }
}
```